# failed without any error message while replacing part of names of columns with other names in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a dataframe which has column names as shown in the `dput` data below.

```
structure(list(mosales = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L), sale123 = c(14.86, 
8.97, 6.44, 463.61, 15.94), totsales = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
30L, 1L), totqty = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 34L, 2L), unqsales = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 2L), x1_rank_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x1_rank_4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), x1_rank_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x1_rank_2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x2_rank_2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), x2_rank_1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), x2_rank_5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), x2_rank_4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x2_rank_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x3_rank_1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x3_rank_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), x3_rank_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x3_rank_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x4_rank_1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), x4_rank_5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), x4_rank_2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), x4_rank_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x4_rank_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x5_rank_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), x5_rank_4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), x5_rank_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), x5_rank_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(36L, 41L, 72L, 79L, 137L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I am trying to do is to replace columns names, which start with `x1_rank, x2_rank .. and so forth`, by the names such that "**x1_rank**" should be replaced with **mosales**, "**x2_rank**" should be replaced with **sales123**, "**x3_rank**" should be replaced with "**totsales**", "**x4_rank**" should be replaced with "**totqty**" and "**x5_rank**" should be replaced with "**unqsales**".

So the final column names would look like:

```
mosales, sale123, totsales, totqty, unqsales, mosales_1, mosales_2,... sale123_1, sale123_2,... totsales_1, totsales_2,... totqty_1, totqty_2,... unqsales_1, unqsales_2,...
```

I tried using a for loop and gsub, as in below. This code ran without any errors but I didn't get what I was looking for. Not sure where is the error.

```
df1 <- df
z <- names(df)

for (i in 1:length(z)){
  gsub(paste0("x",i,"_rank"), z[i], names(df1))
}
```

df is dataframe which can be created using above dput data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this reg `\\bx1_rank[a-zA-Z]*`.

This will match `x1_rank` at the start of the string.

`gsub` lets you replace the found pattern with what you want. Repeat for all the cases you need.

In a loop:

```
repl <- c("mosales", "sales123", "totsales", "totqty", "unqsales")

for (i in 1:5) {
  p = paste0("\\b^x", i, "_rank[a-zA-Z]*")
  colnames(d) = gsub(pattern=p, repl[i], colnames(d))
}
colnames(d)

# 
# [1] "mosales"    "sale123"    "totsales"   "totqty"     "unqsales"   "mosales_1"  "mosales_4" 
# [8] "mosales_3"  "mosales_2"  "sales123_2" "sales123_1" "sales123_5" "sales123_4" "sales123_3"
# [15] "totsales_1" "totsales_4" "totsales_3" "totsales_2" "totqty_1"   "totqty_5"   "totqty_2"  
# [22] "totqty_4"   "totqty_3"   "unqsales_1" "unqsales_4" "unqsales_2" "unqsales_3"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I feel, if there was a `for loop`, it would have been better so that we do not have to write longer repeating codes. Is it possible? Moreover, `replacement="xxxx"` would require to write names of the columns manually which could be a bad practice in coding. :(

Comment: Although, I know I can use something like `replacement=z[1]` for "mosales" and so forth.

Comment: Cool, Thanks very much, it works. I just used z in place of repl and done!

Answer (score 2):

String manipulation functions in the `stringi` package are vectorized over `pattern`, `replacement`, and (optionally) `string`. This is very convenient for your case:

```
library(stringi)

orig <- c(stri_c("x", 1:5, "_rank"))
repl <- c("mosales", "sales123", "totsales", "totqty", "unqsales")
names(df) <- stri_replace_all_fixed(names(df), orig, repl,
                                    vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks Ista for your help and I have specific requirement of using for loop within a code so why i wanted it to be that way without use of any package. :)